# Node JS: Not calling promise reject() callback stops the execution of the program

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

It seems I misunderstand the Promise mechanism. In the following code:

```
async function CreateSession()
{
      var sessionId = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                log.debug("Session created successfully")
                resolve(body["session-id"]);
            }
            else
            {
                log.error("Failed to create session:");
                log.error(error);
                // reject(error);
            }
        });
    });

    log.debug(`Session Id: ${sessionId}`);
    return sessionId;
}
```

The reject() is commented on purpose to understand the mechanism.
When calling the above CreateSession() function as follows and making sure an error is happenning:

```
async function MyFunction()
{
    var sessionId = await CreateSession();
    AnotherCode();
}
```

The entire program stops, the code after await in CreateSession is never reached, AnotherCode() is never called, and even if I put a handler for uncaught exception it doesn't catch any error.

My questions:

- Why does the program stops when reject() is not called?
- If it's an error why it is not called by the handler for uncaught exceptions?
- How do I ignore the an error when a promise fails to run its code?

Comment: Uh, why would the program not to stop, what else do you expect it to do after it has logged the error?

Comment: "*If it's an error why it is not called by the handler for uncaught exceptions?*" - because it's not thrown as an exception anywhere?!

Comment: My main point here is that i don't understand what is happening behind the scenes. What is the piece of code that stop the program? Is is that like an exit(1) called somewhere because resolve/reject was not called? I misunderstand why it is designed this way. I would have expected to leave the decision to the programmer whether I want the  program should be stopped if that request fails.

Comment: Another side effect is that when calling reject() it is printing error messages that i don't necessarily want to see. How do i prevent those messages from being printed to the console?

Comment: No. A node.js program stops when it has nothing more to do. There are no asynchronous operations ongoing, there are no callbacks registered on any such operations after your `request()` is done, so it exits. If you want it to do more, like execute `AnotherCode`, you need to cause it to run by resolving the promise.

Comment: You can prevent the error being printed to the console by handling the rejection of the promise, either with `try`/`catch` around your `await`, or with the classical `.catch(…)`. Just like not letting exceptions go unhandled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you're mixing 2 concepts that achieve the same thing, the creation of a Promise. You are mixing `async/await` and `new Promise`.

That makes it actually like you have 2 chained Promises.

> Why does the program stops when reject() is not called?

Because you are returning a Promise and that by itself demands that either a resolve or a reject callbacks are called.

> If it's an error why it is not called by the handler for uncaught exceptions?

There is no actual error, the only thing that happens is that your if clause is not met.

> How do I ignore the an error when a promise fails to run its code?

Again, the Promise does not fail to run it's code, you're failing to understand the concept.

To make it easier either use something like :

```
function CreateSession(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if( <yourconditionhere> ){
         resolve(res);
      }else{
         reject(error);
      }
   });
}


CreateSession
.then((res) => {
   // code to execute in case of success (resolve)
   // receiving as argument the argument of the resolve call.
   AnotherCode();
})
.catch( error => {
   // code to execute in case of non-success (reject)
   // receiving as argument the argument of the reject call.
});
```

or

```
async function CreateSession(){
   let res = await request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if( <yourconditionhere> ){
         return ...;
      }else{
         return ...;
      }
   }
   return res;
}

async function MyFunction()
{
    var sessionId = await CreateSession();
    AnotherCode();
}
```

Comment: Thx. Why in your code you are putting AnotherCode() within the then({})? Is the point here that when a programmer put an await somewhere the Node engine is stopped an the rest of the code is conditioned by the resolve/reject being called and not simply by the promise to complete? I must say I am confused, seems I don't catch something.

Comment: I think what you 1st have to understand is that async/await is just another mechanism to create a promise. And in the context of promises, you are dealing with asynchronous code, which means, code that only gets executed at a certain point in time, not immediately. Therefore you have to condition the forthcoming code to only be executed at that time, after the 1st code was executed, that's why the AnotherCode() is enclosed inside the .then() , because the .then() maps to the resolve() function, which means, when resolve() is called, .then() is executed.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-promises/ , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=en .

Comment: Normally, these kind of libraries that execute asynchronous requests (i.e. fetch) already return a Promise, so you don't need to implement another one yourself.
Please check also the code on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch .

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the program stops when reject() is not called?

Because of the `await`. The program waits for the promise to either `resolve` or `reject`. It can't detect somehow that the code inside the promise constructor has finished executing (even if it could - what should be the "standard" behavior?) and there is no more code to come.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the execution of the async function to wait for the passed Promise's resolution, then resumes the async function's execution and evaluates as the resolved value.

For some "under the hood" insights, you might want to look at the ES5 code generated by transpilers like Babel (IIRC it uses generators to handle this).

> If it's an error why it is not called by the handler for uncaught exceptions?

The program doesn't know that `error` is an error if it's neither thrown nor passed using `reject`.

> How do I ignore the an error when a promise fails to run its code?

Either `resolve` (instead of `reject`) or `reject` and do the classical try/catch around the `await` code

Comment: Thx. I misunderstand some key points in your first bullet. Why are you saying that there is no more code to run? There isAnotherCode() that can be called within MyFunction()

Comment: I was referring to the code inside the `Promise` constructor.

Comment: Then why AnotherCode() is not executed?

Comment: Because, as I wrote, there is still the `await` part before. The `await` halts the program until the promise is either resolved or rejected. If you neither reject nor resolve the promise (by calling `resolve` or `reject`), nothing will happen and the program will not continue.

Comment: This is exactly my question. Why will it not continue when there is still code to execute after the await?

Comment: Because that's the point of `await` - **wait**ing for the promise to finish. Remove the  `await` and `AnotherCode` will get executed immediately.

Comment: Got you but why it can't see that the code within the promise has completed regardless of resolve/reject being called?

Comment: Your first sentence is not really correct.  The program doesn't stop because of the `await`.  The program exits because there's nothing left to do.  There are no running timers, open sockets, files in the process of being read to, etc...  There's nothing left to do and no possible future events to fire so the program can't ever do anything more so it exits.  That's how node.js works.

Comment: @jfriend00 : why AnotherCode() is not considered as something left to do?

Comment: @isaac.hazan - Well, node.js knows that it can never, ever get to a point where it can run `AnotherCode()` so it's pointless that the code is just sitting there.  It knows this because there is nothing running in node.js that could ever trigger an event which could ever run another line of code. When node.js detects that no code can ever run again in this instance, it exits.

Comment: @isaac.hazan - Things that can generate future events to run future code are timers, open network sockets, listening servers, asynchronous operations in mid-flight (like in the process of reading/write a file), etc...  Node.js keeps a constant count of the number of these things that are running. If node.js gets back to the event loop and the event queue is empty and the count of active operations is 0, then no more code can ever run in this node.js instance.  There's nothing alive that could cause a future event to occur that would cause some callback to get called.  So, it exits the process.